# php preg_replace remove <br> with style attr

Tags: php, regex, html-parsing

```
<br style="clear: both">
```

The following regex doesn't work for me, what am I doing wrong?

```
return preg_replace('#<br[^>]+style="clear:both"[^/>]#is', '',  $output);
```

thank you.

Comment: doesn't work because you don't match space between "clear:" and "both"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your string is always:

```
<br style="clear: both">
```

You can use `str_replace` instead:

```
return str_replace('<br style="clear: both">', '',  $output);
```

---

[**Beware that you shouldn't use regex for html manipulation.**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454)

Use some parser HTML instead.

Answer (score 1):

You may escape chars like **=**, **:**, **<**, **>**, etc.
Something like this:

```
<?php    
return preg_replace('#\<br[^>]+style\=\"clear\:both\"[^/>]#is', '',  $output);
?>
```

More better example:

```
<?php
return preg_replace('#\<br*.?\>#is', '',  $output);
?>
```

Comment: No, those characters have no special meaning, so escaping them is pointless.  Also, the `*.?` in your second suggestion should be `.*?`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
#<br *style="clear: *both"/?>#is
```